# Different writing, same thing: one gives segmentation fault, the other doesn't

Tags: c, if-statement, segmentation-fault, cs50

Is there any reason why this would give segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;

void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) {
    RGBTRIPLE original[height][width];
            
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            original[i][j] = image[i][j];
  
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            for(int k = i - 1; k < i + 2; k++)
                for(int m = j - 1; m < j + 2; m++)
                    if(k < 0 || m < 0 || k == height || m == width) {
                        original[k][m].rgbtRed = 0;
                        original[k][m].rgbtGreen = 0;
                        original[k][m].rgbtBlue = 0;
                    }
}
```

as opposed to this?

```
if(k < 0 || m < 0 || k == height || m == width) {
   original[k][m].rgbtRed = original[k][m].rgbtGreen = original[k][m].rgbtBlue = 0;
}
```

This is the only difference, and yet former gives segmentation fault while the latter doesn't.

I am using CS50 IDE, if it matters.

I cannot give the full context since the code is hundreds of lines, but essentially this just reiterates over every pixel of a bmp image. This only happens with large images whereas with small images neither returns a segfault.

Comment: If any of these indexes is `< 0` you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: I bet that `original` was defined as `struct whatever original[height][width];` and therefore accessing `original[height][**]` or `original[**][width]` invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @Devolus why? In my code the indexes are defined beforehand in for loop statement, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @pmg yes that is true. What would be a workaround?

Comment: You are using `or` this means that, if i.e. `k == -23` the condition is true  and the statements will be executed. Which means `original[-23][m]`. Which is certainly not what you intended.

Comment: workaround? not really: just code around accessing out-of-bounds elements. Or (**BIG BIG OR**) make your array larger than it needs to be so that you have extra elements on top, bottom, right, left ... and **still** avoid writing out-of-bounds!

Comment: @Devolus that's exactly what I intended, though. The idea is to make all pixels out of image boundary black, ie set their rgbt values to 0. `k` doesn't ever go below -1 or above height, though.

Comment: @pmg yes that may be it. Thanks.

Comment: Then you should show a complete minimal sample.

Comment: Post a [mcve] to save us all time.  Certainly `original[][]` is accessed out-of-bounds.

Comment: "`k` doesn't ever go below -1". That is exactly the problem. `k` will be -1 if `i==0` and this is an illegal index.

Comment: Exactly as I said above. If k < 0 you will be out of bounds. This is true for the first loop already, because `k = i-1` where `i= 0`.

Comment: Your condition `if (k < 0 || m < 0 || ...)` is exactly the opposite of what you (probably) want to achieve: That condition is true if any of the indices is outside the valid range.

Comment: @MOehm I understand you, but that's what I wanted actually. I had to treat all pixels outside of image edges as black. My problem was that I thought I could simply access them even if they were out of bounds for `original[height][width]`. Running the opposite condition wouldn't allow me to access the pixels outside of image. The solution is to simply make `original[height][width]` bigger on every side.

Comment: The you might make your array one item bigger and start with `i= 1` to stay in bounds. The same holds true for `j/m`.

Comment: Apparently you are writing a blurring filter for which you must read, but not write outside the bounds of the original image. The idea is not to access them at all, but to say, hey! That's outside the image bounds, so I'll just say you're black. There is no assignment or reading outside the valid ounds involved.

Comment: @Devolus shouldn't it be two items bigger? If I want a black border for all sides, I need `width + 2` and `height + 2`, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Now you understood the problem, you must apply it your solution. But you would still have to make sure that the input values are within bounds. For that particular problem adding an additional item might be enough, depending on where your width/height comes from.

Comment: @MOehm close, but it's actually a filter for highlighting edges. How do I say that treat everything outside of bounds as black without explicitly making `original[height][width]` larger? At first I assumed they're black as default, but that was true for only the majority, not all of them (garbage values, I assume).

Comment: @Devolus I don't understand how one item would be enough.

Comment: Since you want to have a border on each side, you have to add width+2 and height+2, just like you said above. But this must be done by the caller, who provides the array.

Comment: @Devolus gotcha.

Comment: I think you already have you answer, but for the sake of illustration, [look here](https://ideone.com/KyTibX). The "pixels" outside are just ignored and therefore contribute 0. If you wanted them to contribute any other value, you could do that in an `else` clause. (The `continue` structure in that example doesn't realy lend itself to that, though.)

Comment: @MOehm I did exactly that  before. Does that solution avoid reaching out of bounds and producing undefined behavior? As far as I can tell, it doesn't. Plus, the values outside of `image[height][width]` bounds aren't zero. Most of them are, but not all, which puts a wrench in that solution. You could make an `if` statement specifically making them zero, but then the reaching out of bounds problem still remains. That code may work, but not dependably.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to tell me, but your misunderstanding is the same all along: There are no valid values outside `image[height][width]`, so you cannot access them. You can either make your array bigger and re-index your calculations, so that all accesses are to valid memory. Or you can check the bounds and just say: That's out of bounds, I'll use zero (or whatever) instead.

Comment: @MOehm Oh my bad, I didn't notice the `continue` statements in your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C language, it is forbidden to access an array of size N outside the range [0, N-1].
In both case, you access outside this range, this is why you have segmentation fault.

Comment: But why would smaller images or simply rewording the function not trigger segmentation fault? Is it because it's undefined behavior?

Comment: It's UB. Working as expected is a possible outcome. You want to avoid UB at all costs, otherwise you may believe your code is OK when in fact it's just waiting for your boss to type `Y` when you expected `y` ... and barf at a bad time :-)

Comment: It's not forbidden as such, but if you do it, the program has undefined behaviour, so you shouldn't. And yes, undefined means undefined.

Comment: @pmg yeah, the reason this baffled me so much was that the code ran well before, until I rewrote it. Thanks.

Comment: @IloveYeezis Furthemore, a closing bracket } is missing in your first code snippet.

Comment: If the code worked before you rewrote it, this is usually a GOOD indicator for undefined behavior (assuming that you rewrote it functionally aeqivalently).

Comment: @Devolus do I understand correctly that you mean if seemingly irrelevant changes make the code stop working, that means there's UB in both versions?

Comment: Yes. this is usually a good indicator. For example: You do a `printf("%d", val)`and it works and then you change it to `printf("Value: %d", val)` and it suddenly stops working. This kind of thing. If you see errors like that and you can be sure that the change is unrelated, your problem is somewhere else, before that code you changed. This is what UB means.